# Integer multiples of $2\pi$ on $\cos$ function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Suppose you know that the smallest positive value $t$ such that $\cos t=0$ is $t=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, but you don't know other values of $\cos$ and $\sin$.

You also know that $u$ is a real number such that $\cos u=1$ and $\sin u=0$.

Just from this, can you conclude that $u$ must be an integer multiple of $2\pi$?

(You know the usual trig identities, such as $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ and $\cos 2x=2\cos^2x-1$.)

Comment: Ok, what do we know about $\cos$ and $\sin$?

Comment: @Berci Any trig identity you want, such as the ones I included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\sin \alpha = \sin \beta = 0$.  Then
$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin \alpha \cos \beta + \sin \beta \cos \alpha=0,$$
which implies that the zeroes of sine are closed under addition.  Since **sine is an odd function**, they are also closed under additive inverses.  It follows that the zeroes of sine form an abelian group.

If this group is not cyclic (generated by a single element), then it is dense in the real line.  But, since **sine is continuous**, it would follow that sine is identically zero, which contradicts that **cosine has a zero at $\pi/2$** (using the **Pythagorean identity** and your hypothesis).  Therefore the zeroes of sine *are* cyclic, which implies that they have a unique minimal positive element.  It remains to show that this element is $\pi$.  Using the **double angle formula for cosine**,
$\cos 2 x = 2\cos^2 x -1,$ it follows that $\cos \pi =-1$, so that $\sin \pi=0$.  On the other hand, suppose that sine has a minimal root $x \in (0,\pi)$. Then $\cos x = \pm 1$, so that
$$\cos x/2 = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}=0 \text{ or } \pm1.$$
(This is, again, the double angle law for cosine.)
Then $\cos x/2 =1$ since **cosine is continuous**, $\cos 0=1$, and $x/2 < \pi/2$, the minimal positive zero of cosine.  It follows that $\sin(x/2)=0$, which contradicts that $x$ was chosen minimally. So $x \geq \pi$, and $x = \pi$ as seen above.

This answers half of your question.  It remains to study the behavior of cosine on integer multiples of $\pi$.  Suppose that $\cos \alpha=\cos \beta =1$.  Then $\alpha,\beta$ are zeroes of sine, and the **angle addition law for cosine** gives
$$\cos (\alpha+\beta)= \cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta = \cos \alpha \cos \beta =1.$$
As well, since **cosine is an even function**, it follows that the inverse image
$$G=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \cos x =1\}$$
is closed under additive inverses, hence is a subgroup of $\pi \mathbb{Z}$.  This subgroup does not contain $\pi$, since $\cos \pi =2 \cos^2(\pi/2)-1=-1$.  $G$ does contain $2\pi$, however, since $\cos 2\pi = 2 \cos^2\pi-1=1$.  Thus $G$ is generated by $2\pi$, and the set of $x$ such that $\sin x =0$ and $\cos x=1$ is precisely $2\pi \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This may be a bit much for a question tagged (algebra-precalculus). I would assume the "all we know are the trig identities" precludes us from using group theory and such.

Comment: In counterpoint, I might argue that the soft induction in your proof rises above the level of pre-calculus.  I will leave my answer as it stands, in case others wish to see it.

Answer (score 1):

All we know is the trig identities and that $\cos\theta>0$ when $0<\theta< \frac{\pi}{2}$
and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$.

Now, $\cos( \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta) = \sin \theta$ tells us $\sin \theta>0$ when
$0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\sin(0)=0$.

From $\sin(2 \theta) = 2\cos \theta \sin \theta$ we see $\sin \theta >0$
for $0<\theta<\pi$ and $\sin(\pi)=0$.

Continuing like this, and then using $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin\theta$, you will be able to generate a complete list of all the zeroes of $\sin$. Spoiler: the integer multiples of $\pi$. Now you're halfway there, but you also need a list of where $\cos\theta=1$.

From $\cos(2\theta)= 1 - 2\sin^2(\theta)$ you see that $\cos\theta=1$ at precisely the doubles of the zeros of $\sin$. But you've found that the zeroes of $\sin$ are the integer multiples of $\pi$. So you're done. Finally!

Note that we'll never need to assume $\sin$ or $\cos$ are continuous, which is appropriate for a question tagged "precalculus."